# CMake/C++ и подключение подмодулей

Tags: c++, cmake

У меня есть тестовый проект, где я изучаю работу с CMake и C++, его структура выглядит так:

```
+--- CMakeLists.txt
+--- main.cpp
+--- A/
|    +---CMakeLists.txt
|    +---a.h
|    +---a.cpp
+--- B/
|    +---CMakeLists.txt
|    +---b.h
|    +---b.cpp
```

## Содержание файлов:

### Root:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(it3)

add_subdirectory(A)
add_subdirectory(B)

add_executable(MAIN main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MAIN A B)
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "B/b.h"
int main(){
    std::cout << "MAIN:";

    B::BF();

    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

### A:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
set (sources a.cpp a.h)

add_library(A STATIC ${sources})
target_link_libraries(A B)
target_include_directories(A PRIVATE ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR} ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})

install(TARGETS A DESTINATION lib)
install(FILES ${sources} DESTINATION bin)
```

a.h:

```
namespace A
{
    void AF();
}
```

a.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace A{
    void AF(){
        std::cout << "AF!\n";
    }
}
```

### B:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
set (sources b.cpp b.h)

add_library(B STATIC ${sources})
target_link_libraries(B A)
target_include_directories(B PRIVATE ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR} ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})

install(TARGETS B DESTINATION lib)
install(FILES ${sources} DESTINATION bin)
```

b.h:

```
namespace B
{
    void BF();
}
```

b.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <A/a.h>

namespace B{
    void BF(){
        std::cout << "BF!\n";
        A::AF();
    }
}
```

## Проблема:

При запуске всего этого, используя Visual Studio Code, я получаю такую ошибку:

```
[main] Building folder: install_test3 MAIN
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: /usr/bin/cmake --build /home/sl33n/repository/cmake_test_projects/install_test3/build --config Debug --target MAIN -- -j 6
[build] gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/sl33n/repository/cmake_test_projects/install_test3/build'
[build] gmake[2]: Entering directory '/home/sl33n/repository/cmake_test_projects/install_test3/build'
[build] gmake[3]: Entering directory '/home/sl33n/repository/cmake_test_projects/install_test3/build'
[build] gmake[3]: Leaving directory '/home/sl33n/repository/cmake_test_projects/install_test3/build'
[build] gmake[3]: Entering directory '/home/sl33n/repository/cmake_test_projects/install_test3/build'
[build] [ 16%] Building CXX object B/CMakeFiles/B.dir/b.cpp.o
[build] /home/sl33n/repository/cmake_test_projects/install_test3/B/b.cpp:2:10: fatal error: A/a.h: No such file or directory
[build]  #include <A/a.h>
[build]           ^~~~~~~
[build] compilation terminated.
[build] gmake[3]: *** [B/CMakeFiles/B.dir/build.make:63: B/CMakeFiles/B.dir/b.cpp.o] Error 1
[build] gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:171: B/CMakeFiles/B.dir/all] Error 2
[build] gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:124: CMakeFiles/MAIN.dir/rule] Error 2
[build] gmake: *** [Makefile:164: MAIN] Error 2
[build] gmake[3]: Leaving directory '/home/sl33n/repository/cmake_test_projects/install_test3/build'
[build] gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sl33n/repository/cmake_test_projects/install_test3/build'
[build] gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sl33n/repository/cmake_test_projects/install_test3/build'
[build] Build finished with exit code 2
```

Как мне избавиться от этой ошибки, не прописывая в CMakeLists.txt каждой библиотеки что-то вроде?:

```
include_directories(../A)
```

Есть ли более хороший подход к организации CMake проекта?

Comment: Первым шагом было бы неплохо избавиться от подпроектов, оставив один CMakeLists.txt А для каждой библиотеки написать соотв. модуль (если планируется реализовывать cmake установку) либо соотв. include файл.

Comment: @user7860670, можно подробнее об include файлах и как их реализовывать?

Comment: Это такие cmake файлы, которые при включении их в другие cmake файлы добавляли бы в них какие-то свойства, требующиеся включающему файлу для использования компонента, к которой относится включаемый. В данном случае можно было бы добавлять путь /A/include в перечень include_directories

Comment: @user7860670, а как это выглядело бы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка, очевидно, вызвана тем, что при работе в каталоге сборки библиотеки `B` компилятор не может найти файл, который расположен в подкаталоге `A` корневого проекта. Для того чтобы он его нашёл компилятору нужно передать через ключ `-I` корневой каталог проекта.

Соответственно решение — добавить в `B/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
target_include_directories( A PRIVATE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}" )
```

или просто:

```
include_directories( "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}" )
```

Переменная [`СMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR.html) здесь — это встроенная переменная `cmake`, которая раскрывается в полный путь к корневому каталогу с исходниками, а директива [`include_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.19/prop_tgt/INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html) говорит `cmake` добавить указанный каталог к путям поиска исходников. Другие полезные аналогичные переменные — `СMAKE_BINARY_DIR` и
`СMAKE_CURRENT_{SOURCE,BINARY}_DIR` — корневой каталог сборки и текущие каталоги исходников/сборки. `СMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` добавляется к путям включения автоматически, но часто полезны для более изощрённых скриптов.

---

Всё это можно сделать и относительными путями с `..`, но это моветон и в большом проекте может вызвать проблемы при сборке библиотек зависящих друг от друга и использующих включения с видимостью `PUBLIC` или `INTERFACE`...

Comment: Добавил, ошибка осталась.

Comment: @5133n, да, прошу прощения, описался... `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`, конечно...

Comment: спасибо, проект сбилдился.
Не могли бы вы подсказать, в чём заключается это решение?